# How to write invalid data to xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Is there any way to write below data to xml in java. Please help me

```
<tag>  
   <abc="1"/>  
   <cde="a"/>  
   <xyz="3"/>  
</tag>
```

Comment: Yes. there are many ways to do it. Have you tried google with same question ?

Comment: @Jabir Yes, i tried but not able to found any soultion. Because parsers are expecting "abc" as node not as attribute.

Comment: You cant say that is an xml as its invalid. How do you get the data? You could either reformat it to make a valid xml or else you could treat it as a string. Need more info on how you need it? Say for example write this to a file or read such a string and map to a java object etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example...

```
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.CDATASection;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Foobar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* one way */
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/foobar.txt"));
        String data = "<tag>  \n" +
                "   <abc=\"1\"/>  \n" +
                "   <cde=\"a\"/>  \n" +
                "   <xyz=\"3\"/>  \n" +
                "</tag>  ";

        fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());

        /* another way */
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element tag = doc.createElement("tag");
        Attr abc = doc.createAttribute("abc");
        Attr cde = doc.createAttribute("cde");
        Attr xyz = doc.createAttribute("xyz");
        abc.setValue("1");
        cde.setValue("2");
        xyz.setValue("3");
        CDATASection cdataSection = doc.createCDATASection(makeInvalidTag(abc) + makeInvalidTag(cde) + makeInvalidTag(xyz));
        tag.appendChild(cdataSection);
        doc.appendChild(tag);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("/tmp/foobar2.txt"));
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(domSource, streamResult);
    }

    private static String makeInvalidTag(Attr attr) {
        return "\u003C" + attr.toString() + "/\u003E";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not I am expcting the above code will give result in xml file as <abc value="1">

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrongly in a hurry. Forget Document and use ie. FileOutputStream.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Is there any way using second approach. already I am using second approach

Comment: Not really without CDATA because the serializer will escape less and greater than characters as they would otherwise break the XML. I edited the answer. That's an ugly way. Why do you want to write invalid XML?

Comment: Thank you soooo much @olli.puljula.. It works perfectly. In our requirement customer wants to sent the file in that way only.. that file is partially xml and partially not

Comment: In that xml root tag is starts with digit. Can you please help me how to create root tag starts with digit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file:

   `File file = new File(fileLocation);

   fileLocation= <Your_File_path>`
2. Create a file writer object:

   `FileWriter generateXML=new FileWriter(file);`
3. You can write on the file like below:

   `generateXML.write("<tag>");`